# Error while connecting MySQL to Talend

Tags: mysql, installation, talend

I am trying to establish a connection from Talend to MySQL. Could someone tell me the steps to do the same?

I downloaded the MySQL 5 Java connector and saved it in C drive. Post that, I used the DB Connections under Metadata to setup my connection! It asks me for login/password/server and I used 127.0.0.1 as the server path. Do I create the login/password there itself or do I need an existing MySQL login/password to establish the connection. If yes, how do I go about doing that?

Error:
[image: error]

Comment: Please include error messages in the question, not in a linked image! Welcome to SO, btw.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome, @dash2!

Comment: No problem... but could you improve your question by copy-pasting the error?

Answer (score 0):

To connect Talend to MySQL, try to work with workbench; create a database. You should note the login password and port for MySQL.

In Talend, u get tMysqlConnection. In the basic settings, u can put ur host / databasename / port / username and password (The same u've put in MySQL Workbench )

If you are going to use this connection so many times, u can create a metadata with that connection which contains all the parameters and in every job u simply drag and drob your metadata created.